# Font Size too small when drawstring is called

Tags: vb.net, fonts, picturebox, font-size, scaling

I am loading and image onto a picturebox and drawing som text.
when i drag the text it looks big but then when i dra it  or lock it in place it becomes too small. the picture box sizemode is set to Zoom. so huge images are made small. how can i set proper fontsize and preview while in picturebox?

Sub btnLock is responsible for "locking" Text to image
and 
sub Picturebox1_Paint previews

how can i make preview scale down font size or make btnLock scaleup fontSIze

```
 Dim Loc As Point
    Dim Pxy As Point

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
        txtButton.Text = MouseButtons.Left
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            Loc = e.Location
            Me.PictureBox1.Invalidate()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
        Dim myFontSize As Integer
        Integer.TryParse(ComboBox1.Text, myFontSize)
        Dim myFont As New Font("Arial", myFontSize, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic)
        Dim pt As Point = PictureBox1.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtA.Text, myFont, Brushes.Black, pt.X, pt.Y)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLock_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLock.Click
        Dim myFontSize As Integer
        Integer.TryParse(ComboBox1.Text, myFontSize)
        Dim myFont As New Font("Arial", myFontSize, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Me.PictureBox1.Image)
        ' g.DrawString(txtA.Text, myFont, Brushes.Black, Loc.X, Loc.Y)
        g.DrawString(txtA.Text, myFont, Brushes.Black, Pxy.X, Pxy.Y)
        ' Me.PictureBox1.Invalidate()
    End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!-DB35M

Comment: Why don't you define a value for **myFontSize** integer?

Comment: @MacKentoch I am using Combobox1 to change font Size

Comment: Ok, I would debug and add breakpoints to check what happens. I suppose you already did.

Comment: Your Paint event handler draws the text with the font size you asked for, *myFontSize*.  But after you draw the text into the image, it will be scaled the same way as the rest of the image.  As determined by the PictureBox.SizeMode property.  If you want them to match then you must rescale in your Paint event handler the same way.  A bit tricky to get right btw.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you are getting this behaviour as the two `Graphics` objects have different sizes. You object `g` is getting its bounds from the **source** image of your picturebox (without scaling) and your graphics object during `PictureBox1` is getting it bounds from the picturebox **container**. This means they will be different sizes and therefore the `myFontSize` will look like it has different sizes.

Trying to "scale down" the font size according to the down-scaling of the image would be really hard to accomplish. Instead, solve the problem by changing your `SizeMode` to `Normal` and resizing the container to fit the image:

```
PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal
```